# Scalable server hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, server, cloud, web-hosting

I have simple server now (some xeon cpu hosted somewhere), running apache/php/mysql (no docker, but its a possibility) and Im expecting some heavy traffic and I need my server to handle that.

Currently the server can handle about 100 users at once, I need it to handle couple thousands possibly.

What would be easiest and fastest solution to move my app to some scalable hosting?

I have no experience with AWS or something like that.

I was reading about AWS and similar, but Im mostly confused and not sure what should I choose.

Answer (score 0):

The basic choice is:

- **Scale vertically** by using a bigger computer. However, you will eventually hit a limit and you will have a single-point of failure (one server!), *or*
- **Scale horizontally** by adding more servers and spreading the traffic across the servers. This has the added advantage of handling failure because, if one server fails, the others can continue serving traffic.

A benefit of doing horizontal scaling in the cloud is the ability to **add/remove servers based on workload**. When things are busy, add more servers. When things are quiet, remove servers. This also allows you to lower costs when things are quiet (which is not possible on-premises when you own your own equipment).

The architecture involves putting multiple servers behind a Load Balancer:

[image: Load Balancing]

- Traffic comes into a **Load Balancer**
- The Load Balancer sends the request to a **server** (often based upon some measure of how "busy" each server is)
- The server processes the request and **sends a response** back to the Load Balancer
- The Load Balancer **sends the response** to the original requester

AWS has several Load Balancers available, which vary by need. If you are simply sending traffic to a single application that is installed on all servers, a **Network Load Balancer** should be sufficient. For situations where different parts of the application are on different servers (eg mobile interface vs web interface), you could use a **Application Load Balancer**.

AWS also assists with horizontal scaling by providing the **Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling** service. This allows you to specify details of the servers to launch (disk image, instance type, network settings) and Auto Scaling can then automatically **launch** new servers when required and **terminate** ones that aren't required. (Note that they launch and terminate, not start and stop.)

You can further define **scaling policies** that tell Auto Scaling *when* to launch/terminate instances by measuring metrics such as CPU Utilization. This way, the number of servers can approximately match the volume of traffic.

It should be mentioned that if you have a **database**, it should be stored separately to the application servers so that it does not get terminated. You could use the Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) to run a database for you, or you could run one on a separate Amazon EC2 instance.

If you want to find out more about any of the above technologies, there are plenty of talks on YouTube or blog posts that can explain and demonstrate their use.